# How to remove xml declaration from KISSXML?

Tags: ios, libxml2, kissxml

I'm using KissXML (iOS) to create a xml document. Everything works great but when I want to write DOM to NSString using **XMLString** method, then output xml string contains xml declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`). Is there any way to remove this declaration from the generated xml string?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that instead of invoking XMLString method on the DDXMLDocument object, you can invoke XMLString method on the rootElement so:
Instead of (where xml is DDXMLDocument):

```
NSString* str=[xml XMLString];
```

use this:

```
NSString* str=[[xml rootElement] XMLString];
```

Result is an entire xml document without xml declaration.